# Visual Studio Code Contracts Extension - Tooltips only show list of exceptions and not the contract info

Tags: code-contracts

Is there something other than distributing the rewritten assembly xml doc file that needs to be done to get the contract info to show up in tooltips when someone is using my library?  Visual Studio 2010 does with the Code Contract Editor Extensions installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the xml are needed or used. As far as I can tell the info for the BCL comes solely from the `*.Contracts.DLL` files (Program Files\Microsoft\Contracts).

So either the actual libraries should be enough or those helper DLLs should be added.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder where I should place my assembly's contracts dll for the VS CC editor extension to find it?

Comment: @KeithHill, in case you're still wondering to this day: you can move your contracts library to any subdirectory in `Program Files\Microsoft\Contracts`. IntelliSense will automatically use them. Set up a post-build event to automate this process if you're still developing the library that the contracts are for.